# C# Is there a way to make the properties of an object in a class non-editable outside the class itself?

Tags: c#, class, object, oop, readonly

I am looking for a way to have an object in a class and make it non-editable (the object itself AND its properties) outside the class itself but still visible outside.

```
internal class Room
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

internal class RoomController
{
    public Room Room { get; private set; }
    
    public RoomController()
    {
        Room = new Room();
    }

    //Edit the room inside this class
}

internal class Foo
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        RoomController rc = new RoomController();
        
        rc.Room.Description = "something";   // This should not be allowed 
        string roomDesc = rc.Room.Description;   // This should be fine   
    }
}
```

Is something like that possible? I couldn't find anything regarding the issue so I would be grateful if anyone has any ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Removing set from the Description property should do the trick (or make it private like you did to the Room property inside RoomController), but you'll have to pass the correct description to the contructor of the room. Otherwise you'll never be able to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define an interface that only exposes the bits you want public:

```
internal interface IReadonlyRoom
{
  string Description { get; }  //note only getter exposed
}

internal class Room : IReadonlyRoom
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

internal class RoomController
{
    private Room _room;

    public IReadonlyRoom Room => _room;

    public RoomController()
    {
        _room = new Room();
    }

    //edit using _room
}
```